# Enable by default an Actuator Endpoint in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I developed a small library that adds a custom endpoint for the actuator and I like to expose it by default. Spring Boot 2.7.4 only exposes by default `health`.

At the moment, what I am doing is registering an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` to add a property to include `health,jwks` at the last `PropertySource` in the environment. But it seems a little bit fragile. There are other libraries that have to export other endpoints by default (metrics, prometheus...)

This is what I am doing at the moment:

```java
public class PoCEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME = "management.endpoints.web.exposure.include";

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment, 
        SpringApplication application
    ) {
        var propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();
        propertySources.stream()
            .filter(it -> it.containsProperty(PROPERTY_NAME))
            .findFirst().ifPresentOrElse(source -> {
                var property = source.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME);
                var pocSource = new MapPropertySource(PROPERTY_NAME, Map.of(PROPERTY_NAME, property + ",jwks"));
                // Add the new property with more priority
                propertySources.addBefore(source.getName(), pocSource);
            }, () -> {
                var pocSource = new MapPropertySource(PROPERTY_NAME, Map.of(PROPERTY_NAME, "health,jwks"));
                propertySources.addLast(pocSource);
            });
    }
}
```

Is there any way to expose by default that allow me to add several endpoints in different libraries without playing to much with the property sources?

Comment: `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=comma-separated-endpoints` would enable the listed endpoints without your library having to do anything. Your client apps can set this property in `application.yml`. Is this what you want?

Comment: Thank you @AbhijitSarkar, but that is not the case, I'd like to be enabled by default like `health` endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

It’s not exactly clear to me if you’re asking how the client apps that use your library would enable specific endpoints, or if you are writing more than one library and want to expose different endpoints. I’ll answer both.

`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=comma-separated-endpoints` would enable the listed endpoints without your library having to do anything. Your client apps can set this property in `application.yml`.

If you want to set this property by default in your library, one of the easiest ways is to put it in a property file, and load it as a `@PropertySource` on a `@Configuration` bean. I’m assuming your library is a starter and the `@Configuration` bean is auto-configured. If you don’t know how to create a starter, refer to [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-starter).

Comment: property source is not recommended way to add properties in this situation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32117

Comment: Spring Boot member said is not recommend and offer and alternative: `EnvironementPostProcessor`. They are looking for a better solution.

Comment: But **you are** using `EnvironementPostProcessor` and asked for an alternative. When I offered an alternative, you’re referring to what you said you didn’t want to do.